# Sign out button doesn't works. Android - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, cloud, logout

Logout doesn't work. Nothing happens when you click. Does anyone see a mistake?

The code is too long so - here is my MainActivity (https://www.paste.org/90991):

```
    public String userEmail, userName;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseFirestore rootRef;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    public String getUserEmail() {return userEmail;}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if(googleSignInAccount != null){
            userEmail = googleSignInAccount.getEmail();
            userName = googleSignInAccount.getDisplayName();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Witaj " + userName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API)
                .build();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        authStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(firebaseUser == null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };

    private void signOut(){
        Map<String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("tokenId", FieldValue.delete());

        rootRef.collection("users").document(userEmail).update(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid){
                firebaseAuth.signOut();

                if(googleApiClient.isConnected()){
                    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(googleApiClient.isConnected()){
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                signOut();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_exit:
                System.exit(0);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

here is loginActivity (It works): https://www.paste.org/90992

Thank you in advance for all the tips!

EDIT: I added the most important parts of the code here, but I could not add the whole.

Comment: Include code here, not at the other end of links.

Comment: I added the most important parts of the code here, but I could not add the whole.

Comment: Can you check if you have the user added in your database?

Comment: I don't have. I have deleted the account from my phone, but I am still logged in to the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this behaviour because your database is empty. When using this line of code:

```
rootRef.collection("users").document(userEmail).update(map).addOnSuccessListener(/* ... */)
```

You are signing out, only when the token is successfully updated. Because the token is never updated as you don't have any data in your database, the `onComplete()` method is never triggered. To solve this, use the following code if don't need the token:

```
private void signOut(){
    firebaseAuth.signOut();

    if(googleApiClient.isConnected()){
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient);
    }
}
```

Or uninstall the app and sing-in again to generate the user in your database. This will solve the problem for sure.

Comment: Now it works great. As always the best, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
private void signOut(){
    Map<String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("tokenId", FieldValue.delete());

    rootRef.collection("users").document(userEmail).update(map).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid){

            Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                        googleApiClient.disconnect();
                        googleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

});
    }
```

Comment: what do I need to have to be able to use addOnCompleteListener and Plus.AccountApi, because can not resolve method and symbol 'Plus'? In addition, we need two arguments to Map (String and Object, not just String)

Comment: Did you try to import *Plus.AccountApi*

Comment: I added -> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0' and compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:11.8.0'. I don't have an error with Plus.AccountApi. It is only crossed out because it is deprecated.

This has been left: Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener(anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<java.lang.Void>)'

Comment: That's not correct. There is no need to add `Plus.AccountApi` in order to sign out. The lines that are present in OP's code are enough.